# Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER

Tags: python, sqlite

`Python int too large to convert to SQLite INTEGER`

I get that error when int is over then 9126776637782808953

Python version: 3.9.6
OS: Linux (Ubuntu)

How do i fix that?

Comment: You use smaller numbers, I guess.  If you need larger than 2**64, you'll have to go to floating point.

Comment: You can use the type `UNSIGNED BIG INT` to store the large integer number